# Getting the highest count from a monthly count query

Tags: mysql

Dodgy title, I know.

I know I can do this in PHP quite easily, but want to know if it's possible using my SQL query.

I'm producing a bar chart showing new members to my site.

```
JAN  |  FEB  |  MAR  |  APR
-----|-------|-------|-------------
101  |  163  |  282  |  233
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y') as 'year',
DATE_FORMAT(created, '%b') as 'month',
IFNULL(COUNT(user_id),0) as 'total'
FROM users
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created, %Y) = 2013
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y%m')
```

But to develop a bar graph, I need to know what the highest count was. In my example above, I'd like to return **282** as the highest count, so I can calculate the percentage of the bar.

Is this possible and how? I'm thinking maybe I need a sub-query but not really too sure on the best method for performance.

This is what I'd like to return:

```
JAN  |  FEB  |  MAR  |  APR  | Highest_Count
-----|-------|-------|-------|--------------
101  |  163  |  282  |  233  | 282
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02589/24)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` int, `created` date)
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`, `created`)
VALUES
    (1, '2013-01-01'),
    (2, '2013-01-03'),
    (3, '2013-01-07'),
    (4, '2013-02-01'),
    (5, '2013-02-04'),
    (6, '2013-03-04')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(u.created, '%Y') as 'year',
       DATE_FORMAT(u.created, '%b') as 'month',
       IFNULL(COUNT(u.user_id),0) as 'total',
       r2.Highest_Count,
       IFNULL(COUNT(u.user_id),0) / r2.Highest_Count as 'percentage'
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r1.year, max(r1.Total) as Highest_Count
    FROM (  
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y') as 'year',
        DATE_FORMAT(created, '%b') as 'month',
        IFNULL(COUNT(user_id),0) as 'total'
        FROM users
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y') = 2013
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y%m')) AS r1
    GROUP BY r1.year) AS r2 ON r2.year = DATE_FORMAT(u.created, '%Y')
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(u.created, '%Y') = 2013
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(u.created, '%Y%m')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02589/24/0)**:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | TOTAL | HIGHEST_COUNT | PERCENTAGE |
|------|-------|-------|---------------|------------|
| 2013 |   Jan |     3 |             3 |          1 |
| 2013 |   Feb |     2 |             3 |     0.6667 |
| 2013 |   Mar |     1 |             3 |     0.3333 |
```

Comment: I can't tell you how grateful I am, thank you. It's twice as complicated as I initially thought, but very understandable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use -

```
SELECT MAX(`user_id`) FROM `users`
```

From there you can format it.

src = http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html

Comment: TS obviously wants all the rows but also he wants to show percentage - this is what he wants the max for. Also, he wants in pure sql (not php postprocessing). So both the max and all the rows.